# Is there a way to execute a python script with consistent execution time by time padding if necessary?

Tags: python, time

I know the execution time for any python program shall depend on the OS and cannot be controlled by the User. But what I want is the program to go in sleep if the execution time is lower than necessary.

Let's say I have a python program which has a print statement at the end.

```py
def foo():
    ...
    ...
    return(ans)

print(foo())
```

Using timeit I have evaluated the range of execution time taken for foo. Let it be from 0.8 seconds to 5.5 seconds. I choose the execution time of the complete script as 10 seconds to be on the safe side.

I want the program to add delay of 9.2 seconds before print statement if the execution of foo was completed in 0.8 seconds. Likewise a delay of 4.5 seconds if execution was completed in 5.5 seconds.

Comment: How precise do you need to be?

Comment: @ddejohn not much, a resolution of 0.1 seconds works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the execution time of `foo()` using two calls to `time.time()`. You can then compute the amount of time to stall the execution of the program using the computed execution time of `foo()`:

```py
import time

def foo():
    ...

start_time = time.time()
foo()
end_time = time.time()
if end_time - start_time < 10:
    time.sleep(10 - (end_time - start_time))
```

Note that we use `time.sleep()` rather than a `while` loop that repeatedly checks whether enough time has elapsed, since [busy waiting wastes resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196591/17769815).

Comment: Kinda silly to bring up "wasting resources" when time is a resource and OP wants to intentionally waste it but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: works well within the resolution required. Thanks! @BrokenBenchmark

Comment: @ddejohn Yeah, but busy waiting is a general pattern one should avoid. I was going to comment that on your answer, but it was deleted before I could answer. (I wasn't the one who downvoted, for the record.)

Comment: @ddejohn However, time is a different resource from CPU cycles. A sleep allows another process to use those cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just have to sleep for the amount of time that is the difference between the maximum time and actual execution time. you could also make a general purpose decorator.

```py
class padtime:
    def __init__(self, maxtime):
        self.maxtime = float(maxtime)

    def __call__(self, f):
        def _f(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time.time()
            delay = self.maxtime - (end - start)
            if delay > 0.0:
                time.sleep(delay)
            return ret
        return _f

@padtime(9.5)
def foo():
    ...
    return("Answer")
```

that could be applied to any function.