# how to prevent time.sleep() from delaying when away from the computer

Tags: python, time, sleep

I have a python script I wanted to rerun overnight on the company computer, so I made sure to turn off sleep for the computer and then started the script which had these lines

```
while True:
        try:
            ### Large Script
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Done")
        time.sleep(1800)
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "30 Minutes passed")
        time.sleep(1800)
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "1 Hour passed")
        time.sleep(1800)
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "1.5 Hour passed")
        time.sleep(1800)
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "2 Hours passed, Rerunning")
```

what happened is it didn't run because the period is delayed and i found the output something like this

```
2022-06-21 18:02:00 Done
2022-06-22 03:22:00 30 Minutes passed
2022-06-22 07:50:00 1 Hour passed
2022-06-22 10:03:00 1.5 Hour passed
```

while windows is telling me it didn't sleep all night, so what's going on?

[image]

**Update:** [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941177/upper-limit-in-python-time-sleep) don't answer my question since they're giving solutions if the time.sleep() sleeps less than what you requested, my situation is it sleeps for hours when I wanted it to sleep for 30 minutes

Comment: Instead of printing every 30 minutes, try printing each 10 seconds or something so you get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: It's suspicious that the seconds were always zero and that there were no microseconds shown at all. Looks like that output isn't really from that code.

Comment: It's not from the code i manually did it similar to what it was @KellyBundy